# Android Studio - Kotlin with JVM Target 1.8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

The newer version(s) of Android Studio default Kotlin projects to target JVM 1.8.  Considering that Java 8 is about six year old now, that looks like a sensible default, but is there any downside? Any compatibility issues, like not being able to target older API, etc? There is a doc describing certain issues with 1.8 and AS 3.0 - https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support
Does it mean that with the latest stable build of AS (3.6.3 at this time) those issues are gone?